# Exact kernel density value for any point in R

Tags: r, kernel-density, probability-density, density-plot

I was wondering if there is a **R base way to obtain the exact kernel density at any point desired?** As an example, how can I get the exact kernel density at the 3 following points **-2, 0, +2 on X-Axis** in a plot like below?

```
set.seed(2937107)
plot( density(rnorm(1e4)) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use linear interpolation to find it.

```
d <- density(rnorm(10000))
approx(d$x, d$y, xout = c(-2, 0, 2))
```

The precision of interpolation can be higher if you set a larger `n` in `density`. By default `n = 512` so interpolation is based on 512 points.