# Probability Density (pdf) extraction in R

Tags: r, probability-density

[image]

I am attempting to reproduce the above function in R. The numerator has the product of the probability density function (pdf) of "y" at time "t". The omega_t is simply the weight (which for now lets ignore). The `i` stands for each forecast of y (along with the density) derived for `model_i`, at time `t`.

The denominator is the integral of the above product. My question is: How to estimate the densities. To get the density of the variable one needs some datapoints. So far I have this:

```
y<-c(-0.00604,-0.00180,0.00292,-0.0148)
forecastsy_model1<-c(-0.0183,0.00685) # respectively time t=1 and t=2 of the forecasts
forecastsy_model2<-c(-0.0163,0.00931) # similarly
all.y.1<-c(y,forecasty_model1) #together in one vector 
all.y.2<-c(y,forecasty_model2) #same
```

However, I am not aware how to extract the density of `x1` for time `t=1`, or `t=6`, in order to do the products. I have considered this to find the density estimated using this:

```
dy1<-density(all.y.1)
which(dy1$x==0.00685)
integer(0) #length(dy1$x) : 512
```

with `dy1$x` containing the `n` coordinates of the points where the density is estimated, according to the documentation. Shouldn't `n` be 6, or at least contain the points of `y` that I have supplied? What is the correct way to extract the density (pdf) of `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `n` argument in `density` which defaults to `512`. `density` returns you estimated density values on a relatively dense grid so that you can plot the density curve. The grid points are determined by the range of your data ([plus some extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39554039/4891738)) and the `n` value. They produce a evenly spaced grid. The sampling locations may not lie exactly on this grid.

You can use linear interpolation to get density value anywhere covered by this grid:

- [Find the probability density of a new data point using "density" function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28077500/4891738)
- [Exact kernel density value for any point in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43862665/4891738)